# How to create a folder on s3 bucket from python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an s3 bucket `my-bucket` and a python script, where I want to create another folder (`training_data`) within the bucket including a text file. I was told to use `s3fs`, but I can't get it to work so far and I find the documentation to be rather non-intuitive.

What I am trying is the following:

```
import os
import s3fs

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
path = 's3://my-bucket/training_data/'

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as it just creates a folder locally. I already configured AWS credentials by the way. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 is an object storage, it has been designed as a Key-Value store where the key is the full name of the file and the content of the file is the Object.

However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using a shared name prefix for objects (that is, objects have names that begin with a common string, `/` by default). Object names are also referred to as key names.

I would recommend you to use `boto3` package:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client(service_name='s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                                      aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
with open(source_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    self.s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Body=f, Key=s3_prefix)
```

where:

`source_file_path` - the path of the file that you would like to upload.

`s3_prefix` - the desired key name in s3

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the file to S3. It will handle creating the folder for you.

Python's `os` library is for local file system. Recommended to use boto3 library for using a `put_object` API.

Refer: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object